# iptables not starting upon reboot

Tags: iptables, fedora, systemd

I've enabled iptables in systemd with:

```
systemctl enable iptables
```

but after restart when I try `service iptables status`, it shows:

```
# service iptables status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  iptables.service
 iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

But when I start it manually `systemctl start iptables`,  it starts normally.

I'm running Fedora 22.

Comment: I don't know about Fedora 22 but it is worth a shot: Try issuing the command `chkconfig | grep iptables` to check if it is set to start on your current runlevel. If it set to off you can set it on with `chkconfig iptables on`.

Comment: @Isaac thanks,  but iptables is a systemd service in fedora 22,  and can no longer be controlled by chkconfig.   When I run `systemctl list-unit-files|grep iptables`,  it shows iptables is enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Fedora 22 and Centos 7 is shipped with firewalld as default firewall.
I got a the same behavior when testing on a Centos7 when having firewalld and iptables enabled at the same time.

Check to see if `systemctl list-unit-files|grep firewalld` is enabled if so disabled it with:

`# systemctl disable firewalld
rm '/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.service'
rm '/etc/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/firewalld.service'`

Now iptables should start at boot.

Comment: The same as above, but using the "systemctl way":

`systemctl stop firewalld.service; systemctl disable firewalld.service; systemctl mask firewalld.service`